# Incapaz de obtener 100% en code coverage

Tags: c

Estoy desarrollando un código que debe cumplir un 100% de [MC/DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage)

Utilizo la siguiente página para medir la cobertura:
https://www.expcov.com/cgi-bin/expcov/demo.cgi

El código es muy sencillo, das 3 lados de un triángulo y he hecho varias pruebas para que pase por todas las condiciones. El problema es que soy incapaz de cubrir el 100% de MC/DC, hay algo que se me escapa. Parece que el problema está en la condición b < a + c

¿A alguien se le ocurre qué puede ser?

Adjunto el código completo y la entrada con datos de prueba

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checktriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
  if ((c < a + b) && (b < a + c) && (a < c + b)) {
    if (a == b && a == c) {
      printf("Triangulo equilatero \n");
    } else if (a == b || b == c || a == c) {
      printf("Triangulo isosceles \n");
    } else {
      printf("Triangulo escaleno \n");
    }
  } else {
    printf("No es un triangulo \n");
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  int a, b, c, i, n;
  printf("Numero de casos de prueba: \n");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  printf("%d", n);
  printf("\n");

  for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
    printf("Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): \n");
    scanf("%d", & a);
    printf("%d,", a);
    scanf("%d", & b);
    printf("%d,", b);
    scanf("%d", & c);
    printf("%d: \n", c);
    checktriangle(a, b, c);
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Entrada:

```
9
6
5
10
3
3
3
4
4
5
7
2
3
4
3
0
10
10
40
4
15
10
5
4
4
4
5
4
```

Gracias

Comment: No me queda claro lo que estás preguntando. Todos tus `if( )` tienen el correspondiente `else`, por lo que cubres el 100% de los casos posibles. Por tanto, ¿ Lo que quieres es que te proporcionemos casos de prueba que te cubran todos los casos ?

Comment: ¿No tienes la salida esperada? Así sería más fácil ver qué está mal. Por cierto, puedes escribir los 3 lados en una misma línea para facilitar la lectura. El programa funciona igual.

Comment: Sí, creo que puede tener que ver con que me falta un caso de prueba. No entiendo por qué la condición que pongo en la foto se cumple 7 veces (true=7, false=1) pero no cumple la MC/DC indepently accept. Las 2 otras con iguales y sí lo cumplen. CCN = 9, 9 pruebas bastarían

`================================================
  NLOC    CCN   token  PARAM  length  location  
------------------------------------------------
      14      9     99      3      14 checktriangle@3-16@triangulo_corregido.c
      18      2    121      0      19 main@18-36@triangulo_corregido.c
1 file analyzed.
`

Comment: 4 3 0 Esta prueba sobra y falta una.

Answer (score 0):

***Cobertura de condición/decisión modificada***
Cada punto de entrada y salida del programa ha sido invocado al menos una vez, cada condición en una decisión del programa ha tomado todos los resultados posibles al menos una vez, y se ha demostrado que cada condición afecta el resultado de la decisión de forma independiente. Se tiene que  demostrar que **una condición afecta el resultado de una decisión de forma independiente** :

Por ejemplo, en los siguientes casos de prueba:

```
8
6 5 10
3 3 3
4 4 5
7 2 3
10 10 40
4 15 10
5 4 4
4 5 4
```

Output:

```
Numero de casos de prueba: 
8
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
6,5,10: 
Triangulo escaleno 
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
3,3,3: 
Triangulo equilatero 
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
4,4,5: 
Triangulo isosceles 
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
7,2,3: 
No es un triangulo 
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
10,12,40: 
No es un triangulo 
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
4,15,10: 
No es un triangulo 
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
5,4,4: 
Triangulo isosceles 
Marcar los valores de longitud de los lados del triangulo (uno por linea): 
4,5,4: 
Triangulo isosceles
```

Con estos casos cumplimos que cada condición en una decisión del programa ha tomado todos los resultados posibles al menos una vez pero **no** de forma independiente.

**Solución**:
Variar solo esa condición(b < a + c) mientras se mantienen fijas todas las demás condiciones: (c < a + b) & (b < a + c) & (a < c + b) impidiendo el corte de && o cambiando a una condición por decisión:

```
if (c < a + b)
 if (b < a + c) 
  if (a < c + b))
```

Comment: Gracias Francisco. Es la misma conclusión a la que he llegado yo, si el operador && cortocircuita, parece que no hay ninguna manera de evaluar esas condiciones de forma independiente. Me sigue pareciendo raro que se cumpla para las otras 2... ¿Este código nunca podría correr en la NASA que requiere 100% MC/DC a menos que cambien las condiciones por las que comentas? eso es lo que quería confirmar.

Comment: Si así es, en teoría una decisión esta compuesta de una o varias condiciones que se evalúan en conjunto.

Answer (score 0):

Soy un desarrollador de herramientas.
Voy a comprobar si puede ser un fallo.

Basándome en la diferencia en los resultados de ejecución de los dos códigos siguientes, creo que la herramienta es la causa.

```
#include <stdio.h>

bool check(bool a, bool b, bool c)
{
    return a && b && c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    check(true, true, true);
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return (c < a + b) && (b < a + c) && (a < c + b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    check(1, 1, 1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Parece que el código de la medida de cobertura que se inserta no se ejecuta porque la expresión ha sido transformada por el proceso de optimización realizado dentro del compilador.

"Si añades "a &&" y lo pruebas, verás que la expresión original satisface el MC/DC.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He actualizado mi compilador. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo.